# Python: while should stop iterating if 1 of 2 conditions are reached?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I have set a very simple example here:

```
def sourcecode(a,b,c,alternatief=False):
    volume_a, volume_b = 0, 0
    while volume_a != c or volume_b != c:
        print(volume_a,volume_b)
        volume_a += 1
        volume_b += 2

    if volume_a == c:
        return volume_a
    elif volume_b == c:
        return volume_b

print(sourcecode(7,3,5))
```

Of course this will be an infinite loop as always 1 of the two will never reach c. 
But what I try to figure out is how to write my while statement to stop if one of two conditions are met.

Answer (score 6):

It is a relatively simple tweak:

```
while volume_a != c and volume_b != c:
                    ^
```

This requires *both* to be `True` to continue, so stops looping if either one becomes `False`.

With `or`:

```
True or True == True
True or False == True
False or True == True
False or False == False # need both to match to break out
```

With `and`:

```
True and True == True
True and False == False # break out here
False and True == False # or here
False and False == False
```

Comment: Well thanks, this helped indeed. A fairly simple solution but if I break it down in some logic sense (even though in first view it doesn't seems too logic) it actually makes sense :)

Comment: I have added some more information that will hopefully make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `and`, not `or`. When one of the condition is `False`, the loop will quit:

```
while volume_a != c and volume_b != c:
    print(volume_a,volume_b)
    volume_a += 1
    volume_b += 2
```

If you're using `or`, it will stop only when both conditions are `False`. By using `and`, the loop will continue only if both conditions are `True`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

others response are good but you could simply use an infinite loop and returning from it

```
def sourcecode(a,b,c,alternatief=False):
    volume_a, volume_b = 0, 0
    while True:
        if volume_a == c:
            return volume_a
        if volume_b == c:
            return volume_b
        print(volume_a,volume_b)
        volume_a += 1
        volume_b += 2

print(sourcecode(7,3,5))
```